# TFS Sharepoint portal - how to show shared documents from project at collection level?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a simple TFS collection set up, with corresponding sharepoint site.

I have a couple of projects inside that collection - the projects are closely related and each ahve a a few docs in their respective shared documents folders.

When viewing at the "top" collection level:

- Add the Shared Documents web-part for the project to the collection level page (ie show the project level shared documents web-part at the collection level), or
- Aggregate the contents of the shared documents in the projects together to show on the collection level page.

Either way - I just want to be able to see the Shared docs from the projects at the collection level, and I can't figure out how to do that through any of the web part dialogues.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since you talk about only a few docs, would it suit you to add links in the Collection-level to the docs' actual location?

If yes, you would have to insert as available 'file-type' a link in your Sharepoint portal.
Go to you Collection level & open "Shared Documents", then choose 'Settings'>'Document Library Settings'.
In the new page that opens, select 'Advanced Settings' (it's under General). 
In the new page select 'Yes' in the question "Allow management of content types".

If you now go back to 'Settings' you 'll see a new block "Content Types". Click on "Add from existing site content types".
In the new page that opens select & add to the list the "Link to a Document":
[image]

After all these, you can now add in your portal links to docs that reside in different locations within the portal or elsewhere:
[image]

The downside of this approach is that you now have to add all links one by one *by hand*.

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, thanks. I may do this for a couple of the more important documents, to make things obvious. However, I really would prefer to just see everything - the documents are changing right now, and maintaining those links should be a pain.